Navigation error in Blazor when submit a form
This error occurs when I submit a form and execute the method:

I used dependency injection at the top:
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager

By the way, if I prefixed the method name with async, the error would not occur.
This is a Blazor web app running on .NET 8.0.
I checked this github issue#233, but I don't think it's the same as my problem.

We need the error message in English.

@DA ok，i added a picture in English

based on Github issues: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/54203
That exception is thrown and caught by the framework and is used to signal navigation internally. The only reason you are observing it is because you have enabled breaking on first chance exceptions in the debugger.

I'm following the exact same tutorial and have come across the same exact error. After some testing and debugging, I've finally managed to find a solution!
First, make sure that you have set rendermode to InteractiveServer. You can do this on top of your page, like this:
@rendermode InteractiveServer

Next, I know you're using an EditForm, so I'd like you to change OnSubmit to OnValidSubmit:
<EditForm Model="Game" FormName="EditGame" OnValidSubmit="HandleSubmit">

Now we create a method to handle the submit. This should be an async Task, like this:
private async Task HandleSubmit()
{
    GamesClient.AddGame(Game); // Adds game
    NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/"); // Navigates to the homepage
    await Task.CompletedTask; // Indicates that task has completed
}

Without the last line, the code would run twice on my end.
Making use of OnValidSubmit allows you to make use of custom validation, intercepting the default behaviour of a submit. With testing, I had noticed that using a regular button with a navigation would work fine but buttons with type submit would throw an error.
Additionally, when making use of @rendermode InteractiveServer, when you type anything in a field, it would mark it green if the field has valid data, before you even press the button. The opposite is also true. I thought this was a cool built-in feature.

For context, the tutorial on YouTube is called Blazor Full Course For Beginners, created by Julio Casal.
